# How to fix attribute Error in Pyomo model python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo

I am trying to write a pyomo model in python3, but I am facing this error that I can't seem to figure out - 'list' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'. Below is my pyomo model, any help would be appreciated.

```
    R_avg_tolist = [[0.00043159478649482775,
  0.00045388639592182584,
  0.0006735271301199177,
  0.00044026758948786,
  0.0037176592984565836]]

    Cov_list = [[5.884677519869241e-05,
  5.756542207262417e-05,
  6.017027849080026e-05,
  6.180151597797322e-05,
  -0.0005074353586106837],
 [5.756542207262417e-05,
  6.0380562653096757e-05,
  6.613608499966434e-05,
  6.737370769879904e-05,
  -0.0005362752804115953],
 [6.017027849080026e-05,
  6.613608499966434e-05,
  8.206495000024503e-05,
  8.01694525889321e-05,
  -0.0005958716888916681],
 [6.180151597797322e-05,
  6.737370769879904e-05,
  8.01694525889321e-05,
  0.00010129901491226823,
  -0.000608829853150321],
 [-0.0005074353586106837,
  -0.0005362752804115953,
  -0.0005958716888916681,
  -0.000608829853150321,
  0.007373689071617548]]

    import pyomo.environ as pyo
    
    # Optimization Problem
    def create_model(rho,R_avg,Cov):
        
        m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
        init_x = {}
        m.idx = pyo.Set(initialize=[0,1,2,3,4])
        for i in m.idx:
            init_x[i] = 0
        m.x = pyo.Var(m.idx,initialize=init_x,bounds=(0,None))
        
        def Obj_func(m):
            b = []
            mult_result = 0
            for i in m.idx:
                a = 0
                for j in m.idx:
                    a+= m.x[j]*Cov[j][i]
                b.append(a)
            for i in m.idx:
                mult_result += b[i]*m.x[i]
            
            return mult_result
        m.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=Obj_func)
        
        def constraint1(m):
            sum=0
            for i in m.idx:
              sum+=m.x[i]
              return sum ==100  
    
        m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(rule=constraint1(m))
        
        def constraint2(m):
            
            sum=0
            for i in m.idx:
              sum += R_avg_tolist[i]*m.x[i]
    
            return sum >=0.08
    
        m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(rule=constraint2(m))
        
        return m
```

When I run model using below code, I face the attribute error - 'list' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'.

```
rho = 0.0008
model1 = create_model(rho,R_avg_tolist,Cov_list)

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(model1, tee = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but your model has many syntax probs.  It's obviously a course assignment...  Do you have somebody (instructor/TA) to go over this with who can advise a bit?

You didn't include enough info about which line of code caused the issue, but there are several problem areas.  I've posted many simple `pyomo` examples if you scan through some of them, you'll get some ideas, along with the documentation and whatever you have from your course notes....

A few pointers may help:

Do NOT overwrite keywords/functions by using them as variables.  When you write:

```
sum = 0
sum ....
```

you are nuking the python function `sum` by making that name a variable and assigning it the value of 0.  You *should* be using sum in several of your functions with verbiage like:

```
sum(m.X[i] for i in m.idx)    # or similar
```

You seem to be confused on making valid pyomo expressions.  That is the core job of pyomo ... to make expressions and fill the model.  For example, in your `constraint1`, you can just make an expression (without a function) and add it to your model.  You can do a 1-liner there because the constraint is not a "for each".  You could:

```
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.x[i] for x in m.idx) == 100)
```

In general, when you are starting:

Add 1 thing to your model, and then print the model:

```
model.pprint()
```

See if it looks right, if not, fix it.  Then repeat!